# Syntax error (comma) in query expression, header with commas

Tags: vb.net, select, syntax-error, dbf

I am trying to check if value from label1 exist in dbf file column named : "NALOG,C,8". Header in DBF file I can not change, 'cause it represents column's format and field size. But with that I get this error : "Syntax error (comma) in query expression "NALOG,C,8 = @NAL"

Here is complete code :

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\"
    Dim DBF_File As String = "PROMGL"
    Dim ColName As String = "NALOG,C,8"
    'Dim SQLstr As String = "SELECT * FROM " & DBF_File
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password="
    'cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & DBF_File)
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE " & ColName & " = @NAL")


    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAL", Label1.Text)
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            con.Close()
            Label6.Text = "EXIST" & TextBox1.Text
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Focus()

        Else
            Label6.Text = "DOESN'T EXIST"

        End If
    end using
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column that is named this:

```
Dim ColName As String = "NALOG,C,8"
```

Then I would change it too this:

```
Dim ColName As String = "[NALOG,C,8]"
```

Comment: Now I have "No value given for one or more required parameters" but I guess that has nothing to do with column name.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
Dim ColName As String = "NALOG"
```